# How can I query active record models in context of a nested route, DRY style

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, rails-routing

I like my controller to use all ids that the request URL contains without making the controller route specific.

My route:

```
...
resources :users do      
  resources :properties
end
...
```

My controller are the standard scaffold controllers. Lets look at the index method:

```
def index
  properties = Properties.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: properties }
  end
end

def show
    @property = Property.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
       format.json { render json: property }
    end
end
```

Problems with a route like ***/users/10/properties*** is that it doesn't pickup the user_id of 10 and is not using it to create the query. Its querying all properties instead of the subset.

I also makes modifying the url trivial to view other users properties, simply toy with the "id", no need to find a match "user_id" + "id" since "user_id" is ignored.

Of course I can express that explicitly in the code, but that would make it route specific. I like to use the controller in the context of a non nested route as well.

Is there a standard recipe to handle that? Like looking at all parameters that end with "_id"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources
It will help you with this (and much more)

Otherwise you'd need to, in your index action check if the query param is there and if it is, query on that param (Properties.where(user_id: params[:user_id] )

Comment: inherited_resources looks amazing. it really does a lot, is there any downside to it?

Comment: Not that I've come across. You have to think about your controllers a bit differently, but that's a good thing.